# Displaying PDF content in UITextView

Tags: iphone, pdf, uitextview

MY apps deals  with PDF.Here I want to display the PDF content in my app.I can display the contents in UIWebView.Is it possible to diaplay the PDF content in the UITextView..I have added PDF in my resource folder....

Comment: First of all, why do you want to display it in UITextView?

Comment: so... what features you're trying to get from UITextView which you can't get from UIWebView?

Comment: In UIWebView the contents are displayed as in PDF ,but in the Text View i can change the font size,type,line spacing etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no, you cannot display a PDF file inside a UITextView, this class is made to display text with format. Though you can add the UIWebView with the PDF as a subview to the UITextView.